# confusion about oop features in c language,my statement proving that there is many oop features in c also

Tags: c

oop features

1. class: but there is structure and union in c also
2. operator overloading : we can write 0.1+3.4 or 1+3 or 'a'+'b' this is what , + operator working for integer,float,and for character addition, so it's one kind of operator overloading?
3. inheritance: in c when we include any file in another file using include like `include<iostream.h>` so we are including iostream file in another file by this we are achieving
   inheritance also in c.

   in short my question is for each and every object oriented question i m having some argument so can any one help me to clear all the object oriented features comparison with c language.

   c is not a object oriented language but my above arguments proving that, c is also object oriented language

   so i want to more pacific about object oriented features comparing with c language.

Comment: operator overloading is not a oop feature.

Comment: This basically comes down to a question of "what does OO mean". By the usual definition of OO, most of what you've said has no bearing on whether C is an object oriented language or not. It's about equivalent to saying "the ocean is wet, therefore red is really yellow."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 a class is much more then a union or a structure, a class can contains variables AND methods (code] neither a union or a structure can contain logic.

1. operator overloading is not strictly a oo feature, java does not have operator overloading. your example is a limited overloading, you can not make structA + structB work in c
2. there is a big difference between loading a library and inheritance. Inheritance allows you to create a sub type that has all the behaviors of the parent and then allows you to modify them or add some more features. You could do this in C but it would be much harder and very complicated

Your understanding of OO concepts seems rather limited, I would read some basic OO tutorials to get the concepts.

Comment: thank you Sibster for your answer,,, still not getting,i want some more specific answer, actually this question was asked by my friend and he has an argument for each and every oop features , i m not able to give proper answer against his argument , so if he argue with me, what answer should give against his argument? this is the basic argument he has argument for almost all oop features !!! please help me

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't support object-oriented programming as a language, but it doesn't mean you can't implement object-oriented concepts in your code (e.g. encapsulation, information hiding, polymorphism).  You just have to work harder to do it, because the language doesn't help you out.

Bjarne Stroustrup had to do a lot of work to add that language support for OOP on top of C.  C++ isn't a trivial accomplishment.